# A single heap nim game

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

Consider a game where two players remove sticks from a heap. The players move alternately, and the player who removes the last stick wins the game.

A set P = {p1,p2,…,pk} determines the allowed moves. For example, if P = {1,3,4}, a player may remove 1, 3 or 4 sticks.

Your task is find out for each number of sticks 1 , 2 ,…, n if the first player has a winning or losing position.

How to solve this question. Thank You for help.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3486952/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118868/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you two hints. Firstly, A losing position means there exists a move for your opponent to win in a single move, or to bring you to a losing position in a single move. Observe that if you are currently in a winning position, you can put yourself in a winning position within one move.

Secondly, you should label winning positions starting from the very first stick until the last, e.g. since stick $i$ is a winning / losing position for the starting player, stick $i + p$ must be a winning / losing position for starting/second player.

P.S. The game might deadlock for $p_1 > n$, where $n$ is the number of remaining sticks and $p_1 < p_2 < ...$.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to determine which positions are winning positions and loosing positions if you start from the 1.

Using your set {1, 3, 4} as an example, the first player can easily win the game if the number of sticks are either 1, 3 or 4 as he just has to take all.

Counting upwards from 1, we see that 2 is the least number which has not been classified as either a winning position or loosing position so 2 becomes a loosing position for the first player.

Indeed if the heap was of size 2, the first player would be forced to take just 1 and the second player wins by taking the other one.

Since 2 is a loosing position for the first player, 2 + 1, 2+3 and 2+4 are all winning positions for the first player i.e(3, 5, 6).
Then the next number which hasn't been classified as we go upwards is 7. So it is a loosing position for the first player.
His next winning positions would be 7+1, 7+3 and 7+4.

Continuing with this algorithm, you can determine all the winning positions and the loosing positions for the first player.